# PHP strtotime returns a 1970 date when date column is null

Tags: php, date-format, strtotime

I want to display $row->depositdate in dd-mm-yyyy format.

If the date column in database is null the date displayed is : **01-01-1970**

```
echo "<td align=center>".date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row->depositdate))."</td>";
```

If the date is null in database it should display nothing , otherwise the date in dd-mm-yyyy format should be displayed.

Thanks in advance

Sandeep

Comment: Then check if the value is null and if it is, don't expect `date` function to do your job for you - display empty string, otherwise display `date` function output.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

NULL is interpreted as 0 by strtotime, since it want to be passed an integer timestamp. A timestamp of 0 means 1-1-1970.

So you'll have to check for yourself if `$row->depositdate === NULL`, and if so, don't call strtotime at all.

Answer (score 8):

`NULL` is converted to 0 - the epoch (1-1-1970)

Do this instead

```
echo "<td align=center>".($row->depositdate ? date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row->depositdate)) : '')."</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if $row->depositdata [is_null](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) previously or check for 0 after strtotime if the value of $row->depositdata is unrecognizable for strtotime.

```
  echo "<td align=center>";
  if (!is_null($row->depositdate))
  {
     $jUnixDate = strtotime($row->depositdate));
     if ($jUnixDate > 0)
     {
          echo date('d-m-Y', $jUnixDate);
     }
  }
  echo "</td>";
```

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a [Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), relative to the timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied.

more about unixtime and Y2K38 problem:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Answer (score 0):

```
I am able to insert value into DB (SQL Server -- Microsoft) with PHP and value stored is: 2021-03-25 22:45:00

When I trying to fetch the value from DB:

 $db = trim($row_table['db_timestamp']);
 $timestamp = strtotime('m-d-y',$db);
 echo date("m-d-Y H:i:s", $timestamp);

output is : 01-01-1970 05:30:00
```

Answer (score -2):

Oh! 
I know why this happens? 
Simply you have not included "depositdate"
in your SELECT query. 
Firstly Change SQL query to select all with wild card sign 
as shown here

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `yourtable`";
```

Comment: How do you know I have not included "depositdate" in the SELECT query ? Please read the question carefully .....