# Wordpress wpdb->prepare strange error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am trying to use wordpress $wpdb in this way:

```
function check_date($date) {

global $wpdb;

$pub = "publish";

 $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_date FROM " . $wpdb->posts . " WHERE post_name = %s AND post_status = %s;", sanitize_title_with_dashes($result[$i]->title), $pub);
    $cID = $wpdb->get_row( $query );

echo "". date("Y/m/d", strtotime($cID->post_date)) . " == ".$date. "<br />";

return (date("Y/m/d", strtotime($cID->post_date)) == $date);

}
```

The output of echo statement should be:

> 2014/05/31 == 2014/05/31

but instead it shows:

> 1970/01/01 == 2014/05/31

and when i change the code to include only 1 $arg it works in this way i.e.

```
 $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_date FROM " . $wpdb->posts . " WHERE post_name = %s;", sanitize_title_with_dashes($result[$i]->title));
```

It displays the output as under:

> 2014/06/01 == 2014/05/31

which is not correct as it is the date of a draft or revision of the post i am trying to get the date of.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is this coming from?! **`$result[$i]->title`**

Comment: @brasofilo: That explains my silly mistake. I needed to have another argument in my function check_date. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`1970/01/01` is displayed because your query failed. This is the 0 date; the start of the unix timestamp.

Anyway, I doubt that you use the API as intended, but I do not know wordpress, therefore you need to check the wordpress API yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This post: [PHP strtotime returns a 1970 date when date column is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737363/php-strtotime-returns-a-1970-date-when-date-column-is-null) explains your problem. It seems like the extra criteria results in no row being returned, so a NULL value in `post_date`.